# Mac Pro + Dual 27" Cinema Displays brightness & brightness control

Tags: mac-pro, cinema-display

Hardware:

- Mac Pro 4.1 (circa 2009)
- AMD Radeon HD 7950 3072 MB graphics card

I have just connected dual 27" Cinema Displays.

Both work, lots of display space ;-)

Two problems (perhaps related):

1. F1 & F2 keys only adjust brightness on the primary display.
2. 2nd display about (purely estimated) 92% of the brightness of the primary display and just a bit too dim to feel comfortable.  While perhaps just the difference in ages and use of the 2 displays, I wonder if something else might have gone awry?

Any way to adjust brightness of both displays from my keyboard?

Any other adjustment I can make to the brightness of the 2nd display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered a solution to Problem 1.

Control + (F1 or F2) adjusts the brightness of the secondary display.

Still working on problem #2

Comment: Problem 2, I'd get a colorimeter for. Might just be profile. I've a similar rig to yours & my 2 'identical' screens need different profiles.